# Unable to use the Dialogflow CX REST API

Tags: api, rest, postman, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

When testing the dialogflow API on postman, I am getting a 404 error even though I have specified the correct URL while providing the correct parameters for the parent values. Authentication is also validated.

Any help would be appreciated.

For references, here's where I tried to retrieve list of environments from my agent [Heres a pic of the problem. I have provided variables for the ID values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97aMn.png)

I am getting the same error for most of the endpoint values. It is however working on the detectIntent one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got my mistake. I didnt remove the '{parent=}' from the URL, apparantly the curly brackets are part of google's naming convention.